# Options for smaller than byte storage?

Tags: c#, .net

I have long multi-dimensional arrays that contain values that range from  0 - 16.

Currently they are stored like:

```
byte[][,] example = new byte[1024][16,16];
```

This adds up to around 300kb.

Is there a more efficient way to store this data? Since a byte can be 0 - 255, this would perfectly fit a single row of 16 values with a range of 0 - 15.

Comment: Store two nybbles in one byte and use some fancier indexing.

Comment: The range of data that bytes can store is 0-255, not 0-256. That might have been a typo on your part.

Comment: Are you talking about values between 0 and 15, or between 0 and 16? You can only fit two values between 0 and 15 into a single byte.

Comment: zero to sixteen inclusive?  That poses a problem.  If it were zero to fifteen inclusive you could store them in nybbles, but zero to sixteen requires more than 4 bits to store uniquely.

Comment: 300kb doesn't seems to be a big problem. Are you sure that this optimization pays off for the increased complexity required by storing your data in `smaller than byte` chunks?

Comment: I agree with @Steve. If it's purely an exercise I can see how it might be fun but for a production app I think it'd be a mistake to optimize further.

Comment: Well... 0-15 (or 16 possibilities) is half a byte. You could stack two half-byte in one byte using some bitfield magic. Shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: perhaps Compressed? or even as a 16 bit image?

Comment: The .NET Runtime alone takes up enough memory that it's really silly to worry about such small quantities.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Depends on how many of those he has to keep in memory at once.  One copy: no issue; a thousand is a different story.

Comment: @ChrisLively He already said it takes up about 300kb. He hasn't told us how many there are, or what the data is, or anything else that would help us determine alternate ways of storing data (I'm thinking of course of the examples in Programming Pearls).

Comment: I think 300kb is not a problem, so you shouldn't waste your time trying to optimize this :)

Comment: Well the optimization is for an iOS game in Unity3D. Each level is currently running at 300kb, which multiplied out over 50-60 levels is a bit heavy, particularly if it can be a fraction of that. And yes sorry I used the wrong terminology, i meant values 0-15 but arrays with a length of 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BitVector32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) would allow you to pack 8 4-bit values into a 32-bit integer. Since you essentially have 64-bit in each dimension of your array (16 rows of 16 4-bit values if I understand correctly), you might be interested in [this class](http://robkennedy.com/2010/08/17/bitvector64-c-source-code/) too.